# Ruby - Uploading a file using RestClient post

Tags: ruby, curl, rest-client

I have a cURL that I am trying to translate into Ruby.

the cURL is this:

```
curl -i -k -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Authorization: token" -H "Content-Type: image/jpeg" -H "Content-Length: 44062" --data-binary "gullfoss.jpg" http://www.someurl.com/objects
```

My Ruby code is this:

```
image = File.read('uploads/images/gullfoss.jpg')
result = RestClient.post('http://www.someurl.com/objects',image,{'upload' => image, 'Accept' => 'application/json', 'Authorization' => 'token', 'Content-Type' => 'image/jpeg', 'Content-Length' => '44062'})
```

The Ruby code is giving me back a 400 Bad Request.  It's not a problem with Authorization or the other headers.  I think the problem lies with translating --data-binary to Ruby.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks,
Adrian

Comment: In the example I have I am setting the post data to the image but I have also tried leaving that blank.

Comment: Try `image = File.open('uploads/images/gullfoss.jpg','rb') {|io| io.read}`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2863164/how-do-i-use-rest-client-for-ruby-to-post-an-image

Answer (score 7):

There are a few things which might cause the problem.

1. You want to use an actual `File` object with `RestClient`, so use `File.open`; it returns a file object.
2. You are including the image object twice in your request; the actual content is not made clear from your question. You are mixing payload elements with headers, for instance. Based on the signature of `RestClient.post`, which takes arguments `url, payload, headers={}`, your request should take one of the two following forms:

Is the endpoint expecting named parameters? If so then use the following:

**Technique 1:** the payload includes a field or parameter named 'upload' and the value is set to the image object

```
result = RestClient.post(
  'http://www.someurl.com/objects',
  { 'upload' => image },
  'Accept' => 'application/json',
  'Authorization' => 'token',
  'Content-Type' => 'image/jpeg',
)
```

Is the endpoint expecting a simple file upload? If so then use:

**Technique 2:** the image file object is sent as the sole payload

```
result = RestClient.post(
  'http://www.someurl.com/objects',
  image,
  'Accept' => 'application/json',
  'Authorization' => 'token',
  'Content-Type' => 'image/jpeg',
)
```

Note that I didn't include the `'Content-Length'` header; this is not usually required when using `RestClient` because it inserts it for you when processing files.

There is another way to send payloads with `RestClient` explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11388090/ruby-rest-client-file-upload-as-multipart-form-data-with-basic-authenticaion).

Make sure to read through the [official docs on github](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client) as well.

I am also new to `RestClient` so if I'm wrong in this case don't be too harsh; I will correct any misconceptions of mine immediately. Hope this helps!