# Ruby rest-client file upload as multipart form data with basic authenticaion

Tags: ruby, http, post, basic-authentication, rest-client

I understand how to make an http request using basic authentication with Ruby's [rest-client](https://github.com/archiloque/rest-client)

```
response = RestClient::Request.new(:method => :get, :url => @base_url + path, :user => @sid, :password => @token).execute
```

and how to post a file as multipart form data

```
RestClient.post '/data', :myfile => File.new("/path/to/image.jpg", 'rb')
```

but I can't seem to figure out how to combine the two in order to post a file to a server which requires basic authentication. Does anyone know what is the best way to create this request?

Comment: on a not related note: you should accept more answers, its good practice...

Answer (score 31, accepted):

How about using a `RestClient::Payload` with `RestClient::Request`...
For an example:

```
request = RestClient::Request.new(
          :method => :post,
          :url => '/data',
          :user => @sid,
          :password => @token,
          :payload => {
            :multipart => true,
            :file => File.new("/path/to/image.jpg", 'rb')
          })      
response = request.execute
```

Answer (score 3):

RestClient API seems to have changed. Here's the latest way to upload a file using basic auth:

```
response = RestClient::Request.execute(
  method: :post,
  url: url,
  user: 'username',
  password: 'password',
  timeout: 600, # Optional
  payload: {
    multipart: true,
    file: File.new('/path/to/file, 'rb')
  }
)
```

Answer (score 1):

The newest best way may be that:
the link is [enter link description here](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client)

```
  RestClient.post( url,
  {
    :transfer => {
      :path => '/foo/bar',
      :owner => 'that_guy',
      :group => 'those_guys'
    },
     :upload => {
      :file => File.new(path, 'rb')
    }
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example with a file and some json data:

```
require 'rest-client'

payload = {
  :multipart => true,
  :file => File.new('/path/to/file', 'rb'),
  :data => {foo: {bar: true}}.to_json
      }

r = RestClient.post(url, payload, :authorization => token)
```