# Showing 400 bad request when try to post file via rest API with Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api

I'm try to post a file using `RestClient` with Ruby on rails, I have try to conver below `curl` command:

```
curl -H 'Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN' -F 'file=@FILE_PATH' https://api.com/api
```

When converting with `RestClient` like below:

```
res = RestClient::Request.new(
        method: :post,
        url: 'https://api.com/api',
        :payload => {
            :file => File.new("#{Rails.root}/public/Sample.docx" , 'rb')
        },
        :headers => {
            :Authorization => "Bearer 155c5e5c4feea51b386fdfe204abc60b7f4025fb91988519de869525217b4702",
            :content_type => "multipart/form-data"
        }
    )

    res.execute
```

On this code showing `400 Bad Request`

What I'm doing wrong with this code?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your post is a duplicate of this one [Ruby - Uploading a file using RestClient post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10687120/ruby-uploading-a-file-using-restclient-post)

In your case, try changing content_type to `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document`

List of MIME types can be found here: [What is a correct mime type for docx, pptx etc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4212861/what-is-a-correct-mime-type-for-docx-pptx-etc)